# Create an unordered list from an Xpath query using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I can create a list in XSLT when it is a a straight forward XPath query, but when I want to create a list of all child elements where the name = something, I cannot get it to work. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<flights
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="flights.xsd">

<flight flightid="1">
    <flightno>EK98</flightno>
    <callsign>UAE98</callsign>
    <airline>Emirates Airline</airline>

    <plane planeid="1">
        <name>Airbus</name>
        <registereddate>07-06-10</registereddate>
    </plane>

    <registration>3A6-EDJ</registration>
    <altitude height="feet">41000</altitude>
    <speed ratio="mph">564</speed>
    <distance unit="miles">erf</distance>

    <route>
    <routename>FCO-DXB</routename>
        <from>
            <iatacode>FCO</iatacode>
            <airport>Fiumicino</airport>
            <country>Italy</country>
            <city>Rome</city>
            <latitude>41.8044</latitude>
            <longitude>12.2508</longitude>
        </from>

        <to>
            <iatacode>DXB</iatacode>
            <airport>Dubai Intl</airport>
            <country>UAE</country>
            <city>Dubai</city>
            <latitude>25.2528</latitude>
            <longitude>55.3644</longitude>
        </to>
    </route>

    <course bearing="degrees">154</course>

    <journey>
        <distance type="miles">2,697</distance> 
        <time>PT5H30M</time>
    </journey>

</flight>
```

I want to create an unordered list containing the child elements text of the plane/name node when it is equal to Airbus. Here is my attempt in the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">flights</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="body"> 
            <xsl:element name="ul">
                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                    <xsl:text>width:100px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="flights/flight/plane[name='Airbus']"> 

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:text>list-style-type:none; width:100px; margin:0 auto;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:value-of select="name" />

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the result will be like this:

```
Name: Airbus
Registered Date: 07-06-10
```

Can someone show me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should learn what "literal result elements" and "attribute value templates" are. They will make your XSLT code much more concise.

To answer your question: Your code doesn't work because you call `apply-templates` on a `plane` element but have a template matching `name` elements. Try a template that matches `plane` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>flights</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <ul style="width:100px; margin:0 auto; padding: 0;">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="flights/flight/plane[name='Airbus']"/> 
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plane">
    <li style="list-style-type:none; width:100px; margin:0 auto;">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice it helped me figure things out!